Fire Barrier for Gap Under Stud Bay
I discovered this gap under the house today while plugging a nearby leak in the duct.  Photo is in the crawl space looking up between the joists.

This spot is also sandwiched above a foundation beam, leaving room for a hand to reach in there but no power tools.  The gap looks too big for duct putty.
Is there something I could easily attach to the floor sheathing that would bring this up to code?  Maybe scrap 1" board and liquid nails, followed by fire barrier caulk/putty around the edges?

Isn't unfaced fiberglass insulation considered an acceptable fire block?

@Huesmann Maybe in situations where the entire stud bay is filled.  That's not the case here.  And I don't think that applies to penetrations either.

Try filling with Fireblock Foam.
You may have to apply it in 2 stages to fill the big hole, but I have seen it filling gaps as big as you have.

That's a good point.  I've seen it on the shelf but never needed it before.
